# Using a variable to store a knockout template

Tags: knockout.js, mustache, knockout-2.0, templating

New to knockout and loving it so far cut a 700 line jQuery mess into 150 lines. The one part I am not really liking is the templating. I want to be able to create a file similar to this

```
module.ViewModel.views = {
   'view1' : '<div data-bind="foreach: data">TEMPLATE</div>'
};

// in my view model set something like 
ViewModel.view1Template = module.ViewModel.views.view1;

// then in my html have
<div data-bind="template: view1Template()"></div>
```

I would like to be able to do this possibly with mustache if that matters but
really I just want to add reusability to my templates not a fan of having them
referenced by IDs directly in the html. The other reason I would like to do this
is in my views folder I have other templates that use mustache but not knockout 
would like to keep my formatting consistent across all JS templates.

### UPDATE

The answer below seems like currently the closest thing to what I want to do
I did it slightly different

```
for (var view in module.views){
    var node = $("<script/>", {
        "type" : "text/html",
        "id" : view,
        "text" : module.views[view]
    }).appendTo("body");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the elements into the DOM dynamically and apply the ko binding afterwards:

```
var html = $.parseHtml(module.ViewModels.views['view1'])[0];
ko.applyBindings(model, html);
$('#content').append(html);
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/VHUcF/

---

I just realized that I might have answered only half of your question. Sadly the template binding handler only accepts an `element id` as argument and no elements. This however is easy to fix by adding the templates to the DOM before applying the bindings:

### HTML

```
<script id="templates" type="text/html"></script>

<div id="content" data-bind="template: templates.answerList.id"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var templates = {
    answerList: '<ul class="answer-list" data-bind="template: { name: templates.answer.id, foreach: answers }"></ul>',
    answer: '<div class="answer" data-bind="text: text"></div>'
};

// insert templates into DOM
for (var name in templates) {
    var html = templates[name];
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    $(element).append($.parseHTML(html)[0]);
    element.id = 'tpl_' + name;
    $(element).attr('id', element.id);
    templates[name] = element;
    $('#templates').append(element);
}

answerModel = {
    answers: [
        { text: 1 },
        { text: 42 },
        { text: 667 }
    ],
    templates: templates
};

ko.applyBindings(answerModel, $('#content')[0]);
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/VHUcF/1/

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a better solution to this problem. It no longer requires you to add a ".name" when specifying the template.

### HTML

```
<script id="templates" type="text/html"></script>

<div id="content" data-bind="template: templates.answerList"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var templates = {
    answerList: 'Answers: <ul class="answer-list" data-bind="template: { name: templates.answer, foreach: answers }"></ul>',
    answer: '<li class="answer" data-bind="text: text"></li>'
};

var templateIds = {};

for (var name in templates) {
    var id = 'tpl_' + name;
    $(document.createElement('div'))
        .append($.parseHTML(templates[name]))
        .attr('id', 'tpl_' + name)
        .appendTo('#templates');
    templateIds[name] = id;
}

answerModel = {
    answers: [
        { text: 1 },
        { text: 42 },
        { text: 667 }
    ],
    templates: templateIds
};

ko.applyBindings(answerModel, $('#content')[0]);
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/VHUcF/3/

### Note

This attempt requires you to either pass the `templates` as model attribute or define `templates` at the global scope. You can also just write `"tpl_"` + ' which I find even more natural to use.

```
<div data-bind="template: 'tpl_answers'"></div>
```

If you do not want to put the `script` element containing the templates in the HTML just create it from the JavaScript as well.