# Store Knockout Templates in Database

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on building a fairly complex notification system for a project and I would like to figure out the best way to store templates for the various types of notifications in the database.

I have found a few similar posts [Using a variable to store a knockout template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611936/using-a-variable-to-store-a-knockout-template) suggests loading all of the possible templates into the DOM before binding the viewmodel.  This solution would work, but doesn't seem to scale very well.  Does knockout provide a way to load a template based on an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout has extensibility points that allow you to add your own template engine or your [custom template sources](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html).

I have had several projects where I use this functionality to create a template engine that defaults to looking in a JavaScript object first for a template string. There are a number of ways that you could do it. Here is the way that I implemented mine: https://github.com/rniemeyer/SamplePresentation/blob/master/js/stringTemplateEngine.js.

After loading your template from the server, you would then just do:

```
ko.templates[templateName] = response;
```

At any time you could easily remove the template from this object.

Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/erytN/

Comment: I like this solution, it is very clean, thanks!.  Now that I can load templates via ajax, is it possible to use a separate template for each li in a ul that has been bound with a foreach?

Comment: Yes, the template name can be determined dynamically via a function. Here is a sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/yfQAnM?p=preview (jsFiddle is not working for me at the moment).